# Highchart labels are selected if I hover over tool-tip, while dragging the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highchart, which I want to drag left or right. I also have a tool tips over the chart candles / columns. I drag the chart by left clicking on the mouse and them I am dragging it around. But, in case while dragging, my mouse goes above the tool tip, not only tool tip but all other X and Y labels are selected.

Here is some simple snippet example:

```js
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      boostThreshold: 1
    },
  },

  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: [
     [Date.UTC(2018, 0, 1), 10],
     [Date.UTC(2018, 0, 2), 10],
     [Date.UTC(2018, 0, 3), 10],
     [Date.UTC(2018, 0, 17), 10]
    ]
  }]
});
```

```css
#app-wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/boost.js"></script>
<div id="app-wrapper">
  <div id="container" style="height: 600px; min-width: 310px"></div>
</div>
```

In order to better understand my issue, here is a [video](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cYhqbnkAJ7) about it.
Any ideas how to prevent this selection of the labels to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use the `panning` feature? It prevents the behaviour visible in your case. Test the demo with bigger data under below API link.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.panning

### EDIT!

Yes, you are right, I noticed this behaviour too. It seems like a regression. I reported it on Highcharts GitHub issue channel where you can follow this thread:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13566

It happened after last release - in the previous one everything works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d69r1zok/, so as a temporary workaround you can use previous version of Highstock.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/8.0.4/highstock.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see that even that example has the same behavior, which I want to prevent. Labels are selected there as well, when user hovers over the tool-tips.